# Dropbox files_put internal server error

Tags: dropbox

I need to make a upload to dropbox with only an access token and the /files_put request. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put

I tried it with cURL, but nothing goes...then i tried it with jquery ajax to test...and become an `NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error`.

Here is my JS code:

```
var data = "TEST";
var token = '-';

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/test.html?access_token=' + token,
  type: "put",
  data: data
}).done(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
}).fail(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

// Edit:

mh...i tried it 3 more times...and it goes oô

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" probably indicates that it was just an intermittent server issue on Dropbox's side.